# Webpart missing webpart catalog entry when build with vsewss but deployed with stadm

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, stsadm, vsewss

I have the exact problem of not getting any webcatalog entry for a webpart if i deploy via stsadm. The project of this webpart is generated with vsewss and build with it. The very webpart entry can be accessed if its deployed through vsewss' "deploy" command. But i have to make the deploy process with stsadm because of an automation reason.
any ideas ?

thanks a lot.
koray.

Comment: "...any webcatalog entry..."
what i meant was : "...any webpart catalog entry..."

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the features when deploying via stsadm, VSeWSS does that for you and hides the need while you are developing.